# Facebook JS Integration Error

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have the following code right below the body tag of my application

```
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({appId: '136904373......', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
  };

 (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.session) {
  alert('Logged In');
  } else {
  alert('Not Logged In');
}
});
</script>
```

I'm currently getting the following error "FB not defined for  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) which makes me believe that the FB.init is not being loaded correctly.  Anyone have any ideas (I've obscured the last 6 digits of my app idea on purpose)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The getLoginStatus may not complete if the init call is missing valid parameters, such as the appId, or if the domain on which you've loaded the page does not match the site domain configured for the application.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest adding your methods to the init function to make sure that they run after it's been initialized.  It's possible that your code is being executed before the javascript file is finished loading since you're loading it asynchronously.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({appId: '136904373......', status: true, cookie: true,
         xfbml: true});
     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
         if (response.session) {
           alert('Logged In');
         } else {
           alert('Not Logged In');
         }
     });
  };

 (function() {
  var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
  e.src = document.location.protocol +
  '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
  document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());

</script>
```

Comment: that removed the error, but now the FB.getLoginStatus is not working and none of the alerts are firing.

Comment: @phil - Have you tried looking at it in firefox/firebug to see what is going on?